# How to create a tree from a markdown file?

Tags: python, markdown

I would like to create a tree from a markdown file using Python. From what I have researched, it seems that I can use Python's markdown module to do this.

For example by using this file: https://github.com/Python-Markdown/markdown/blob/master/markdown/treeprocessors.py

I am stuck because I am not sure how to access the modules which Python-Markdown have not quite exposed to end users.

Here is what I would like to do for an example Markdown file:

```
# Heading 1

## Heading 2

Line 1
- Bullet 1
  - Bullet 1.1
```

I would like to be able to receive an output that has a structure something like this:

```
tree = process_markdown(markdown_text)
```

And `tree[0].title` can contain `"# Heading 1"` and `tree[0].value` can contain the entire markdown text inside of "# Heading 1" and including "#Heading 1".

Likewise, `tree[0][0].title` be equal to `"## Heading 2"`.

Would ideally also be able to have a tree element represent `"- Bullet 1"` and the sub-bullet be included in the text in the value of that tree element.

I hope this makes sense. Now, I believe this can be obtained using the functions/classes in Python-Markdown but I am not able to figure out the syntax of those inside functions as to how to extract it.

Edit:

1. As I was researching further, stumbled upon the documentation for creating extensions for Python-Markdown. And in there is this reference to tree - https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/api/#working_with_et. I can tell that this is what I think I need to figure out how to use, but still unable to because not able to figure out the syntax and how to use the related functions in Python-Markdown.
2. This question from 2014 is similar. The first answer there suggests [Mistune](https://github.com/lepture/mistune), however, mistune does not seem to create the tree either.

Comment: Wondering also if it would be better to convert the markdown to html, and then parse html using BeautifulSoup tree structure.